# Checking if a number in an array divides another number in the same array

Tags: php, math

What I need to accomplish is,

I have an array,  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

I need to check if any numbers in the array divides any other number in the array perfectly. (%=0) If yes, unset the the number.

Its over my head and I cant get it working and everything I tried gives me infinite loops and its making me ill. (lol)

I am not including any codes, because all I could come up with is a nested forloop which doesnt work :(

So here is a sample :

Input array :2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Output = 5 6 7 8

Any idea guys?

UPDATE:

Cracked the nut myself with bit more debugging. (Incase if that can be helpful for someone in future.)

```
// use array_unique, array_values and $size = sizeof($array)
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
for ($j = $size - 1; $j > $i; $j--)
    if ($numbers[$j] % $numbers[$i] == 0)
    {
        unset($numbers[$i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should nonetheless post your attempt.

Comment: Also, shouldn't your output be 2-8? since they're all divisible by 1?

Comment: @NiftyDude - The code has broken Algorithm so its actually a non working nested for loop. :(

Comment: @NiftyDude - Edited the question. 1 wont come in the input array. And 2 divides 8 perfectly, so we unset 2.Similarly, we unset 3 because it divides 6 perfectly. Same for 4 since it divides 8 perfectly. so `2 3 4 5 6 7 8` gives `5 6 7 8`

Comment: Sounds like you DO need a nested for loop. Iterate over it once to get the first number of your division and again for the second number.

Comment: Is your input array always sorted?

Comment: @Mathieu - No. It can be random.

Comment: @Mathieu, should that matter?

Comment: @W.Goeman - Yeah, I thought so, but I end up getting non working stuff for almost an hour of trying. and I deleted it out of frustration. I will try to code it again and post here.

Comment: @W.Goeman - Yes, I think so. So we will only divide the bigger number with small number.

Comment: if numbers always sorted and ordered. Cut it half and take the 2nd part

Comment: @W.Goeman It won't change the algorithm, i wanted to know if we need to go over the whole array or just part of it.

Comment: @Mathieu, valid argument, your version would be double speed :)

Comment: @safarov - I dont think that works for all inputs. Are you sure?

Comment: @safarov - Not good for degenerate cases like `array(2,4,8,16,32,64,128,...)` or `array(1001,1002,1003,1004)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will *not* do this in real code, just because I think you want to do that yourself.

```
LoopA iterating the intput array:
  LoopB iterating the input array:
    check division of loopA value and loopB value, and add the value of loopA to a new array accordingly
  End loopB
End loopA
Print the new array
```

Note: This is not complete, but it certainly should give you a start on how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

For sorted ordered number

```
$arr = array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);

$half_c = ceil(count($arr)/2) - 1;
$result_array = array_slice($arr, $half_c);
```

**Edit:** For random array you can cut half again, and iterate only first part of array. Prime number theory also can help to write faster algorithm for first part of array.

Comment: Sorted as in continous numbers or the numbers just sorted ascendingly?

Comment: It doesn't give the expected result if you remove 14 from your array

Comment: @Mathieu - Thats probably because the size of array is ODD and cant be divided by 2? but I am not sure!! 

Anyways, the numbers can be random, but I can sort it ascendingly, but that doesnt mean, the number are going to be ordered.

Comment: My point was you can't just cut your array in half, this input doesn't work either: array(2,23,43,65,53,67)

Comment: I was basically looking for one with Sorted numbers which arent essentially ordered. But I learned something new from this as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$arr = range(2,20);
$size = count($arr);
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    for ($j=$size-1; $j>$i; $j--) {
        if ($arr[$j]%$arr[$i]) continue;
        unset($arr[$i]);
        break;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [9] => 11
    [10] => 12
    [11] => 13
    [12] => 14
    [13] => 15
    [14] => 16
    [15] => 17
    [16] => 18
    [17] => 19
    [18] => 20
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++)
    {
        if($arr[$i] != $arr[$j] && $arr[$i] % $arr[$j] === 0)
        {
            unset($arr[$j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your algo divides the number with the same number hence unsetting the whole array.

Comment: there. Now it should be okay.